# JavaScript: Parse a long date into a shorter one

Tags: javascript

I'm using AJAX to pull in an RSS feed and show a list of items. However the date that comes back is super long and needs to be shorter.

e.g. `Mon, 11 Jun 2012 17:53:35 PDT` to become just `11 Jun 2012 17:53`

Is it possible to do this with javascript?

The code looks like this currently:

```
for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 5; i++) {

                            var item = feed.items[i];

                            html += '<li>'
                            + item.updated;

                            html += ' | <span class="title">'
                            + '<a href="'
                            + item.link
                            + '">'
                            + item.title
                            + '</a>'
                            + '</span></li>';

                        }
```

So I need to do something to that `item.updated` object.

I've done a quick search on parsing dates, but not found anything I can make use of.

Comment: Btw, consider a JavaScript templating engine (e.g. Handlebars), which is superior to manual string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this RegEx:

```
var result = "Mon, 11 Jun 2012 17:53:35 PDT".replace(
    /[A-Z][a-z]{2}, (\d+) ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):\d+ [A-Z]{3}/,
    "$1 $2 $3 $4:$5"
); // result = "11 Jun 2012 17:53"
```

Or even simpler:

```
var result = "Mon, 11 Jun 2012 17:53:35 PDT".replace(
    /[A-Z][a-z]{2}, (\d+ [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d+ \d+:\d+):\d+ [A-Z]{3}/,
    "$1"
); // result = "11 Jun 2012 17:53"
```

Even more simpler:

```
var result = "Mon, 11 Jun 2012 17:53:35 PDT".match(
    /(\d+ [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d+ \d+:\d+)/
)[0]; // result = "11 Jun 2012 17:53"
```

But if you care about timezones, i.e. want to display the client's timezone instead, you can do this:

```
var Result = new Date("Mon, 11 Jun 2012 17:53:35 PDT").toString().match(
    /([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d+ \d+ \d+:\d+)/
)[0]; // result = "Jun 12 2012 08:53" // client's timezone, GMT+8 for example
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var longdate = "Mon, 11 Jun 2012 17:53:35 PDT";
var shortdate =  datestr.match(/\d[^:]*:\d\d/)[0];
//   ->  "11 Jun 2012 17:53"
```

Comment: It might be even better to explicitly specify the format: `/\d\d \w{3} \d{4} \d\d:\d\d/`

Comment: @FelixKling I had some doubts about `/\d?\d \w{3} \d{4} \d?\d:\d\d/` pattern, but finally decided not to post it.

Comment: Forgot the year... but yeah, it would also depend on how months/dates < 10 are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could just strip everything before the first white space and after the last colon. That is easy with [`indexOf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [`lastIndexOf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`substr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
date = date.substr(date.lastIndexOf(':')).substr(0, date.indexOf(' '));
```

Of course you'd have to adjust this if the format changes.

Comment: Technically correct answer but this solution would result in "11 Jun 2012 17:53:35" not "11 Jun 2012 17:53".

Comment: Oh, I did not note the seconds... then it should be `date.lastIndexOf(':')`... updated.